# How do you modify file content based on a certain pattern in S3

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have many json files (sample given below) present in compressed format in a S3 folder (say s3://data/) as foo.json.gz, foo1.json.gz, foo2.json.gz. One of the category (say 1010) has been mistakenly assigned and it needs to be changed across all files to 1020. How do we go about making this change and re-packaging these files in S3 with modified content?

```
foo.json
    {
      "flower": "lilly",
      "animal": "cat",
      "category": "1010"
    }
    {
      "flower": "rose",
      "animal": "dog",
      "category": "1000"
    }
    {
      "flower": "daisy",
      "animal": "cat",
      "category": "1010"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest & efficient way is:

1. Get all those files in an EC2 Instance which is in the same region as the Bucket is, to minimize the cost.(using `aws cli`)
2. Decompress the *.gz files(using `gunzip`)
3. Pragmatically update json files.(using `php`)
4. Re-compress the files.
5. Copy files back to S3.(using `aws cli`)

Comment: The file sizes are really huge and I don't think that this is an option

Comment: The S3 as its name says is too simple to do this stuff that you want it to do. You'll need either a Lambda or EC2 instance to do that changes.